# BCrypt: how to compare two hashes?

Tags: hash, spring-security, cryptography, passwords, bcrypt

I'm using SpringSecurity's `BCryptPasswordEncoder` (which uses `jBCrypt`) to hash my passwords.

How to check if two hashes represent the same password, if they are hashed with the same strength? If the strength are different, can the hashes be compared in this case?

Comment: Because the salts will be different, you cannot tell from the hashes, whether the original passwords where the same or not. The cost factor (strength) doesn't matter in this case.

Answer (score 1):

> If the strength are different, can the hashes be compared in this case?

No, that would make the whole concept of strength pointless. You need to know the strength used in order to properly use BCrypt.